# LINQ Query is running slow but only on two of my statements

Tags: c#, linq, sqlperformance

I have 2 linq statements below that are part of a larger query. I have about 6 other statements that do very similar things as the the below 2 statements. My query without these 2 statements executes in about 237ms. When I add these 2 it adds on about 10 seconds of time.

The demandXPCILStatuses table has about 30k records and the demand has about 13k.
The PCILStatuses table has 6 records in it.

After doing timing on other tables that have about the same amount of records I have pretty much ruled it being too much data which I never really thought it was anyways but thought I would run some tests.

```
DemandXPCILStatus = (from demandXPCILStatus in demandXPCILStatuses
                     where demand.ID == demandXPCILStatus.DemandID
                     && demandXPCILStatus.Active == true

                     select demandXPCILStatus).FirstOrDefault(),


PCILStatus = (from demandXPCILStatus in demandXPCILStatuses
              join PCILStatus in PCILStatuses
              on new { A = demandXPCILStatus.PCILStatusID, 
                       B = demandXPCILStatus.DemandID, 
                       C = demandXPCILStatus.Active } 
              equals new { A = PCILStatus.ID, B = demand.ID, C = true }

              select PCILStatus).FirstOrDefault(),
```

Here is how my tables are designed

I [![DemandXPCILStatus][1]][1]

[![PCILStatus][2]][2]

I tried to post an image of my database design but I don't have enough points to do that.

So here is how it is designed

```
DemandXPCILStatus
ID (PK, int, not null)
DemandID (int, not null)
PCILStatusID (int not null)
PCILTime (datetime, null)
LastUpdatedOn (datetime, null)
Active (bit, null)

PCILStatus
ID (PK, int, not null)
Status (nvarchar(50), null)
Code (nvarchar(10), null)
Class (nvarchar(30), null)
```

At this point I don't know what else to try. Any suggestions? FYI this is my first LINQ query so I have almost no idea what I am doing.

Comment: Better to post generated SQL.

Comment: I would capture the SQL statements executed on behalf of your LINQ (e.g. with SQL Profiler is MS environment) then run those queries directly and examine their index usage.

Comment: Please post the generated SQL along with any indexes on the tables, and share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: `B = demand.ID` appears to be a typo?

Comment: You should tell what type of LINQ this is about, for example Entity Framework and which exact version. Also, you really need to show how these code fragments are part of a larger query. It's important to know if the entire query can be translated into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dapper to retrieve data and put it into memory before running the query. The table DemandXPCILStatus was returning just over 30k records. I know I didn't post the rest of my query but it is a pretty heavy use of LINQ and I guess 30k records was just too many for performance issues. I filtered out data on that table before putting into memory and that portion of the query went from like 4.5 seconds to like 2ms.

I guess I was a little unclear on the amount of data linq could handle and map to complex objects. But now that I know I fixed up my query and it went from running and displaying in about 15 seconds to 1.2 seconds.